# Multiple linear regression python

Tags: python, numpy, linear-regression

I use multiple linear regression, I have one dependant variable (var) and several independant variables `(varM1, varM2,...)`
I use this code in python:

```
z=array([varM1, varM2, varM3],int32)
n=max(shape(var))
X = vstack([np.ones(n), z]).T
a = np.linalg.lstsq(X, var)[0]
```

How can I calculate the R-square change for every variable with python ? I would like to see how the regression changes if I add or remove predictor variables.

Comment: What is the `var` variable?

Comment: it is the dependant variable. in my case, it is a concentration

Answer (score 2):

If the broadcasting is correct along the way the following should give you the correlation coefficient `R`:

```
R = np.sqrt( ((var - X.dot(a))**2).sum() )
```

One full example of multi-variate regression:

```
import numpy as np

x1 = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6])
x2 = np.array([1,1.5,2,2.5,3.5,6])
x3 = np.array([6,5,4,3,2,1])
y = np.random.random(6)

nvar = 3
one = np.ones(x1.shape)
A = np.vstack((x1,one,x2,one,x3,one)).T.reshape(nvar,x1.shape[0],2)

for i,Ai in enumerate(A):
    a = np.linalg.lstsq(Ai,y)[0]
    R = np.sqrt( ((y - Ai.dot(a))**2).sum() )
    print R
```

Comment: There is no such variable shape, so this implementation does not run.

Comment: @rjurney it does run. `shape` actually is not a variable but an attribute of the `ndarray` object... check if you have such an object...

Comment: shape tells you the size of the array